# How to install PHP composer inside a docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I try to work out a way to create a dev environment using docker and laravel.

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
&& chmod -R o+rw laravel-master/bootstrap laravel-master/storage
```

Laravel requires composer to call composer dump-autoload when working with database migration. Therefore, I need composer inside the docker container.

I tried:

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
--install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

But when I call

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose exec app composer dump-autoload
```

It throws the following error:

```
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"composer\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
```

I would be more than happy for advice how I can add composer to the PATH within my dockerfile or what else I can do to surpass this error.

Thanks for your support.
Also: [this](https://github.com/andrelandgraf/laravel-docker) is the gitub repository if you need to see the docker-compose.yml file or anything else.

Comment: Is there a need to reinvent the wheel? Why not use out-of-the-box solutions for docker, PHP and Laravel (like [Laradock](http://laradock.io/) that covers pretty much everything you need and is easily configurable)?

Comment: Alternatively, there is always the possibility to use composer as `.phar` checked in as part of the repository.

Comment: Are you sure your container is successfully build? This script already makes composer executable. 

docker run -it --rm php:7.1.3-fpm bash
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
--install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
composer --version
Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:59

So problem is not in the docker or composer itself, probable wrong-config or some issue with docker-compose

Comment: @AITak, thanks for the answer, I will check it out!

Comment: @d3jn this is the first time I work with docker and I want to rebuild this laravel + docker walking skeleton to learn from it. Thanks anyway for pointing it Laradock!

Comment: @d3jn of course not, but this is only one possible scenario - try to think of all the people who will arrive at this post because they have a custom image build that also needs composer. Workarounds for specific use cases tend not to be very useful on SO.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I can install composer adding this line on my test dockerfile:

```
# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

It works for me, to test if the composer are installed i access to my container bash and execute:

```
composer --version
Composer version 1.6.5 2018-05-04 11:44:59
```

Comment: Isnt composer --version just returning output from host machine? Or where do you call it?

Comment: you need to run the image generated with `docker run -dit my-image` command, after that you need to execute `docker exec -it container-id sh`, and with this command you can access to the container terminal, when you are on the container terminal you can execute the `composer --version` command to validate  that this is installed on your container

Comment: Since Composer 2.0 is out and many projects still need the 1.x version, you can also pass --version to the installer for a specific Composer version as such: `RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=1.10.22
`

Comment: Better to get it like so: `COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer`, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58694421/1155833)

Answer (score 333):

You can perform an in-line [Multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) using [composer](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/) image so you will basically just copy `composer` binary into the PHP docker image.

In Dockerfile :

```
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: Just be aware that `--from` is fairly new and won't be available in all environments.

Comment: Note if you have packages in your `composer.json` which can only be installed from source then you will also need to install `git`.

Comment: What about the xdebug?

Comment: If you need a specific Version, this works fine, Tank you. I am using this
`COPY --from=composer:2.1.8 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: I received following error:

`invalid from flag value composer:latest: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

Comment: My problem solved. I just stopped `firewalld` service on system

Comment: This is SO fast and amazing! Does anyone know if it's safe to use this with other libraries such as nodejs for instance?

Answer (score 7):

This is how i do it with Laravel 8.4 in 2021 to deploy it to CloudRun in Google Cloud:

Dockerfile

```
#Get Composer
FROM composer:2.0 as vendor

WORKDIR /app

COPY database/ database/
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --no-dev \
    --prefer-dist

COPY . .
RUN composer dump-autoload
```

// some more custom steps like

```
FROM node:14.9 as frontend
...
FROM php:7.4-fpm
...
```

// Copy Composer dependencies

```
# Copy Composer dependencies
COPY --from=vendor app/vendor/ ./vendor/
COPY . .
```

// Some more custom steps

```
...
```

End of my Dockerfile to launch app with cleared optimized cache

```
# Run Laravel commands
RUN php artisan optimize:clear

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080

EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: be aware that it's not recommended using `artisan serve` for production.

Comment: I had to add `--ignore-platform-reqs` since the Composer image didn't have all the requirements like php version that are in my `composer.json`

Answer (score 4):

Create an executable of your composer file using

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
--install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same error code. Do you have an idea what could possibly be still missing?

Answer (score 3):

use `composer` in dockerfile using `curl`

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM 8.1.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Answer (score 2):

Use actual [docs](https://getcomposer.org/download/):

Dockerfile:

```
# Install composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 1):

We have basicly the same command running with the difference,

```
--install-dir=/usr/local/bin
```

Alternatively, you should add the composer bin files path to the $PATH variable.

```
export PATH=$PATH":/usr/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to suggest another way.

Dockerfile:

```
RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add bash
RUN alias composer='php /usr/bin/composer'
```

Answer (score -6):

My problem solved. I just stopped `firewalld` service on system